# Directory password protection for an Apache illiterate person?

Tags: security, apache, passwords

i am an Apache Illiterate person, and i need very simple password protection for a directory using a .htaccess file. **very simple one.**
i also wonder how tutorials simply tells me "put the **.htpasswd** file in the path.." i tried to create a .htpasswd file but failed to do that. if someone volunteers to help please keep in mind i use win server 2008 and please consider that my experience in Apache is almost zero.

Comment: Thank Jon i followed your advice and i want to share the following link to really "create" the file http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/download_htpasswd_generator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to generate your htpasswd file: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

You should get a hash back from that and just place that in your htpasswd file. I **very strongly suggest** that you do not put your htpasswd file in your document root. It would make it accessible via apache.

Edit for clarification:

For example, your apache webserver serves this directory: `C:\www\htdocs`, and you want to protect this directory with username and password: `C:\www\htdocs\secure`. You create this .htaccess file and put it in your `C:\www\htdocs\secure` directory:

```
AuthType BASIC
# You can choose whatever name you want here
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile C:\www\htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

You see the `C:\www\htpasswd`? You need to create that file. Go to that htpasswd-generator link above. Enter a username, enter a password, click on "Create .htpasswd file", the page will give you a text field with your username and a bunch of gibberish. Copy that whole thing and create the file `C:\www\htpasswd` and paste that into the file.

That's it.

Not sure how much simpler it can get.

Comment: is it a must to generate htpasswd. is it possible to insert username and pw in the htaccess file?

Comment: Not if you want to use HTTP authentication (i.e. you go to page and browser pops up a dialog asking for username/password). You need an htpasswd file and it must be hashed.

Comment: vote up for you, however, i need more simplification because i was not under estmating myself calling me an "apache illiterate"

Comment: see edit. This question should really be on serverfault.com though

Comment: Thanks Jon, it worked for me. i just needed to download a local htpasswd generator, really nice http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/download_htpasswd_generator.html